# mongodb: how to create a calculated field using python (pymongo)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Is there a way to create a calculated field in mongodb using pymongo?

```
example = {
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": 2,
    "calculated_field": "field1" + "field2"
}
```

The calculated field must always keep the formula, if "field1" will later be modified, the result must update.

I have read mongodb documentation and I can see it can be done with aggregation pipeline but pymongo's documentation is not really clear on this procedure.

Edit:

I am trying, at the moment, to insert a new field as below but the field is not added.

```
    pipeline = [
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "calculated_field": {"$sum": ["field1", "field2"]}
        }
    }
]

dbCollection = database["col"]

dbCollection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: can you post the aggregation example you have used

Comment: I have tried like in the edit and other examples from pymongo documentation but nothing seems to work. I'm a little lost and I think I'm missing something.

Comment: try to search for mongodb middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of different options based on what your goals are.

1. You can use the aggregation pipeline to calculate the sum:

   ```
    [
        {
            '$addFields': {
                'total': {
                    '$sum': [
                        '$field1', '$field2'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
   ```

   The result will be a document that has the total field.  Keep in mind that this will not store the total in your database.

   ```
     {
         field1: 5,
         field2: 3,
         total: 8,
     }
   ```
2. You could create a Change Stream to monitor field1 and field2 to check for changes.  When changes are made, you could automatically update the total that is stored in your database.  See https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/python-change-streams for more information on how to create Change Streams in Python.
3. If your database is stored in [MongoDB Atlas](http://cloud.mongodb.com) (MongoDB's fully managed database-as-a-service), you can use a Trigger to monitor field1 and field2 for changes.  Triggers are built on the same concepts as Change Streams.  Triggers are a bit simpler since you don't have worry about hosting and managing the Change Stream yourself.  See https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/triggers/ for more information on Triggers.

Comment: I have tried the exact pipeline you described but the field is not added. From python I have tried both "dbCollection.aggregate(pipeline)" and "database.command('aggregate', "collection", pipeline=pipeline, explain=True)".

Comment: anyway.. I have used another approach but thank you for the help and good read!

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working! 

To clarify further - the aggregation pipeline does not save the results to the database unless you add a stage to specifically do so like $out (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/).  If you don't use $out, the results of the pipeline will be returned to you so you can see them and work with them.